# Why is Regex giving me the who start of the string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm writing a generic Smoke Test I need to pull out the version number in each page title so that I can log it along with the results, however, for some reason my Regex is bringing out the whole start of the string (Including the pattern it's supposed to be starting after.

```
string title = "Random text RECOGNITIONPATTERN 9.0 (ENVIRONMENT)" ;
string searchstr= ".*RECOGNITIONPATTERN (.*) ";
Regex reg = new Regex(searchstr, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 
string result = reg.Match(title).Groups[0].ToString();
```

I'm expecting result to equal "9.0", however, what I'm actually getting is "Random text RECOGNITIONPATTERN 9.0"

Any thoughts

Comment: `Groups[0]` returns the whole match. Try `Groups[1]` for your actual capture group

Comment: Thanks that works. But why when the rest of the language is zero based have one bit that isn't :|

Comment: It's not that "it's not 0 based" because there IS a Groups[0] so c# is still 0 based, it's just a rule of implementation that "index 0 contains the entire input string". Most regex engines feature this. See my answer, and use named capturing groups. Side note, in the EPPlus library for writing excel files indexes start from 1, because that's what excel sheets start from. The author made an implementation decision that "1 shall refer to the first row" but his choice didn't mean that c# was no longer 0-based, he just chose it because Excel numbers the first row as 1

Answer (score 3):

Because by default in a Match, `Groups[0]` contains the entire input string. Access `Groups[1]` instead, or better, give your capturing group a name:

```
string title = "Random text RECOGNITIONPATTERN 9.0 (ENVIRONMENT)" ;
string searchstr= "RECOGNITIONPATTERN (?<v>[0-9.]+)";
Regex reg = new Regex(searchstr, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); 
string result = reg.Match(title).Groups["v"].ToString();
```

You also don't need the `.*` at the start of the pattern, and I'd recommend that you more accurately define the chars you want to capture than `.*` if possible -> you want version numbers so consider `[0-9.]+` which is "one or more of 0-9 or .". Perhaps even consider `\d+[.]\d+`

Comment: @Big Ian: be careful with `.*` pattern; e.g. in case of `"Random text RECOGNITIONPATTERN 9.0 (ENVIRONMENT) and more";` you'll get `"9.0 (ENVIRONMENT) and"`. Either use *more specific* match `(?<v>[0-9.]+)` or at least use `.*?` pattern - match as *few* as possible

Comment: For safer patterns instead of `.*` +1

Comment: @DmitryBychenko indeed.. his `.*` only stopped after the version number thanks to a trailing space in his pattern.. But had the rest of the string had a space in it it would have been an issue because of the greediness of the quantifier